# Plotting imaginary part on y-axis against real part on x-axis of complex momentum

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to plot a complex momentum in complex plane where the y-axis shows imaginary values and x-axis shows the real values. I tried ReIm command but it plots Re and Im parts not Re vs Im.
Below is an example which plots Im and Re parts but I need Im vs Re. Any suggestions please?

```
Clear[m, M, s, t]
    m = 0.34
    M = 5;
    t = m^2 + M^2 - s/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[s - 4 m^2] Sqrt[s - 4 M^2];
    tplot = Plot[{Im@t, Re@t}, {s, 4 m^2, 4 M^2}, PlotRange -> All, 
      Frame -> True]
```

Comment: `m = 0.34;
M = 5;
t = m^2 + M^2 - s/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[s - 4 m^2] Sqrt[s - 4 M^2];
tplot = ParametricPlot[ReIm@t, {s, 4 m^2, 4 M^2}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Frame -> True]`

Comment: Dear @cvgmt I tried Parametric plot earlier but was not sure about it. Thanks for this suggestion, it is understood now.